# How to use ClickHouse windowFunnel mode?

Tags: clickhouse

I wanna use [windowFunnel()](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/parametric-functions/#windowfunnel) function in ClickHouse. This is my query:

```
SELECT level,
       count() AS count
FROM (
      SELECT device_id,
             windowFunnel(6000000000000)(creation_time, event_id = 100,
                          event_id = 101) AS level
      FROM event
      WHERE ((creation_time >= '2021-08-01')
          AND (creation_time <= '2021-09-30'))
        AND (event_id in [100,101])
      GROUP BY device_id)
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level ASC;
```

I want ClickHouse to return event sequences that doesn't intervene other events. for example if the sequence is 100 => 102 => 101 it should stops finding 100 => 101 at 102.
ClickHouse document is considered this feature under windowFunnel *strict_order* mode. But when I use that in this way:

```
SELECT level,
       count() AS count
FROM (
      SELECT device_id,
             windowFunnel(6000000000000, ['strict_order'])(creation_time, event_id = 100,
                          event_id = 101) AS level
      FROM event
      WHERE ((creation_time >= '2021-08-01')
          AND (creation_time <= '2021-09-30'))
        AND (event_id in [100,101])
      GROUP BY device_id)
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level ASC;
```

ClickHouse throws an error saying:

```
Code: 170, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Bad get: has Array, requested String (version 21.7.2.7 (official build))
```

I don't have any idea how to use modes in windowFunnel() function?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could find out how I can query CH using `windowsFunnel()` modes. I should remove arrays:

```sql
SELECT level,
   count() AS count
FROM (
  SELECT device_id,
         windowFunnel(6000000000000, 'strict_order')
(creation_time, event_id = 100,
                      event_id = 101) AS level
  FROM event
  WHERE ((creation_time >= '2021-08-01')
      AND (creation_time <= '2021-09-30'))
    AND (event_id in [100,101])
  GROUP BY device_id)
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level ASC;
```

I just can't figure out why CH documentation is using [] in `windowsFunnel()` syntax, I think there is a mistake here:

```
windowFunnel(window, [mode, [mode, ... ]])(timestamp, cond1, cond2, ..., condN)
```

Comment: There is no mistake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form An option can be represented through squared brackets [ ... ]. That is, everything that is set within the square brackets may be present just once, or not at all